# Unique constraint in database-first approach

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm have database with many unique constraints.

I'm aware of that entity framework doesn't know anything about them. So I need to add them to the model manually. But in

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

There is no Unique keyword.

I created new attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class UniqueKeyAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

and added it to my model:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(DeviceInstance))]
public partial class DeviceInstance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [UniqueKey]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Even that
`Model.IsValid` is always returning true even if there is already that value in the table.

What code should I write to change this behavior?

Comment: What's the logic of your UniqueKeyAttribute or is this empty like you pasted it? Are you aware that checking the uniqueness requires a call to DB (which is not the case with other data annontation attributes like Required, MaxLength, etc)?

Comment: Thanks. At this moment You can see as it is. Empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple answer to your question is that Entity framework doesn't support unique keys so the only way is to set the unique constraint is in in the database (as you in fact did). By doing so appropriate exceptions will be thrown when you try to insert/update new rows in the DB in case of a lack of uniqueness, which you can then catch and handle.